# How to extract data from json file with multiple arrays?

Tags: python, json

I'm writing a small flask app, that accesses a json-API.
All the urls from the json file should then be extracted and put into a list for further use. The code in question:

```
@app.route('/booro/<tags>') # <tags> acts as search
def process(tags):
    r=requests.get('https://example.com/post/index.json?'+tags+'&limit=1') #gives me a json file with only one array
    z = r.text[1:-1] # to remove "[" and "]" so that it can be loaded
    i = json.loads(z)
    m = i['file_url']
    return m
```

The code above then presents me just a link on the generated page as expected.

But if I set `&limit` to 2 or higher, I get this error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/user/Schreibtisch/FlaskProxy/maindrive.py", line 19, in process
    i = json.loads(z)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 342, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 1278 (char 1277)
```

The problem is that the downloaded json-file then contains multiple arrays that can't be parsed. It looks something like this:

```
{"id":1383185,"tags":"new main default","file_url": "example1.com"} {"id":1383185, "tags":"vivid original alternative","file_url": "example2.com"}
```

Is there a way to extract values with the same key across multiple arrays?

Comment: Can you show a bit more of the JSON or provide the real endpoint?  It isn’t clear what (...) really represents.

Comment: Is your json valid?

Comment: It's from a danbooro-type service and I'm not comfortable of showing the actual json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be removing `[` and `]`, since the returned object is a JSON array and setting the `limit` to `1` will return you an array with just one object in it. You need to parse the response content without modifications, i.e.

```
i = json.loads(r.text)
```

In case of `limit==1` you will have:

```
[{'file_url': 'example1.com', ...}]
```

In case of `limit==2` you will have:

```
[{'file_url': 'example1.com', ...}, {'file_url': 'example2.com', ...}]
```

etc.
By removing `[` and `]`, `json.loads` tries to treat the response as a single JSON object, instead of a JSON array of objects, i.e. trying to parse something like:

```
{"file_url": "example1.com", ...}, {"file_url": "example2.com", ...}
```

which is not a valid JSON

That being said, you would have to do something like this:

```
r = requests.get(...)
response_content = json.loads(r.text)
for obj in response_content:
    file_url = obj['file_url']
    # Do something with your file_url here. Ex. append to list m.append(file_url)
```

Comment: Not removing the the `[]` and setting `json.loads(r.content)` gives me `TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'`

Comment: oh, wait I didn't configure the below part

Comment: can you edit you post so it says ` 
json.loads(r.text)`? Because I somehow can't edit your post so that I can accept the answer. It worked.

Comment: Here you go. r.json() might also help